# can not use ctrl+C in Pycharm under win7

Tags: python, windows-7, pycharm, meta-key

How to change "copy and paste" into ctrl+c/v ??
Thx !!!
I don't know what meta key is.

Pic of edit menu

[image]

Comment: Isn't it already like that? Are you using the default keymap?

Comment: Did you read the user documentation  for PyCharm?  I'm sure it would clarify it there.

Comment: Traditionally ALT, I think, but presumably configurable.

Comment: alt +c will open the "Code" menu. I have changed something, I don't remember what they are >_<... I will read user documentation, thank you ....> <

Comment: File --> Settings --> Keymap --> choose "Default". I changed it into something like "Mac OS X". =__=....... problem solved...

Answer (score 1):

As your menu already lists <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and you are on windows, there is only one modifier left on a normal keyboard, and that is the windows key, <kbd>Win</kbd>.

If the windows key doesn't work, then you need to look into the user documentation and possibly contact support. In some esoteric cases back in the days, you could use <kbd>Esc</kbd> to simulate the pressing of <kbd>Meta</kbd>, but that was mainly for Unix-like operating system.

And if going even more esoteric you had the [Space-cadet keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-cadet_keyboard) which had seven modifier keys. Four keys for bucky bits: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Meta</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd> and <kbd>Hyper</kbd>, and three shift keys: <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Top</kbd> and <kbd>Front</kbd>. This keyboard had the possibility to print over 8000 different characters. But I reckon that you don't have a space-cadet keyboard.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Win key doesn't work. I must have changed something. I will read the user documentation.

Comment: File --> Settings --> Keymap --> choose "Default". I changed it into something like "Mac OS X". =__=....... problem solved...